# excel export cannot get much data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I have a code that gets data from mysql with php and exports it to a excel file, its this :

```
<?php
$xls_filename = "export_".rand(100000,999999).".xls"; // Define Excel (.xls) file name

// Header info settings
header("Content-Type: application/xls");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$xls_filename");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

/***** Start of Formatting for Excel *****/
// Define separator (defines columns in excel &amp; tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; // tabbed character

$slct2 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM forms_answers WHERE ans_formid='{$identity}'");
$slct2->execute();

while($name = $slct2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $stmt2 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM forms_answers_details WHERE ans_id='{$name['ans_id']}'");
    $stmt2->execute();

    // Start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
    for($i=0; $i<$stmt2->columnCount(); $i++) {
        echo $stmt2->getColumnMeta($i)."\t";
    }

    print("\n");
    // End of printing column names

    // Start while loop to get data
    while($row = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $schema_insert = "";

        for($j=0; $j<$stmt2->columnCount(); $j++) {
            if(!isset($row[$j])) {
                $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
            }
            elseif(isset($row[$j])) {
                $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
            }
            else {
                $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
            }
        }
        $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert .= "\t";
        print(trim($schema_insert));
        print "\n";
    }
}
?>
```

but the problem is that this code just exports data to an extend, lets say it nearly exports a 8*20 excel table and cannot export data more than that limit. instead it exports Array,NULL and page codes. anyone can suggest what should i do to fix this problem?

Comment: can you share an example with us?

Comment: you need to export data in crunch i.e place limit in sql query

Answer (score 1):

$slct2 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM forms_answers WHERE ans_formid='{$identity}' LIMIT 1000");

$stmt2 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM forms_answers_details WHERE ans_id='{$name['ans_id']}' LIMIT 1000");

try with this it is might be possiblity that Db server set limit.

change limit as per data

else there is another possibility that its process breaks in middle due to insufficient memory and execution time.

try with these two lines as well

ini_set('max_execution_time',300);
ini_set('memory_limit','512M')

put these two lines at the before the fetching data;

it will help you.